# How to debug a return value that is not ever stored as a local variable in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Every so often, I find the need to debug this type of code:

```
function DoSomething(int parm1)
{
     return  SomeClass.SomeMethod(parm1);
}
```

In other words, I need to see the return value of `SomeClass.SomeMethod(parm1)`;

The only way I know of currently to do this is to rewrite the code like this:

```
function DoSomething(int parm1)
{
     var returnValue = SomeClass.SomeMethod(parm1);
     return returnValue;
}
```

Then I can put a break point on the second line and inspect the value of `returnValue`.

Is there a way to inspect this value without rewriting the code?

Comment: Do a breakpoint on the whole line and mouse hover on the `return` statement.

Comment: Hovering on the `return` statement did not work for me.  I had to look in the auto/locals window as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[Autos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows)** debug window (Ctrl + D, A). It will show the result of the called function. See the image -> 'ConsoleApp2.Program.Return returned' is the result of the function.

[image]

**NOTE**: This will show the result once you've step out of the function. So not exactly what you need, but it can be useful in chained calls where several functions are called this way.

Comment: I selected this as the answer as you gave a screenshot which was very helpful.

Comment: Note that this is the AUTOS windows, not the LOCALS window which looks the same, but works differently.

Answer (score 1):

Click Shift+F9 or Ctrl+Alt+Q on that part and it open Debug.QuickWatch.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Quick Watch window

> You can use the Watch (Debug / Windows / Watch / Watch (1, 2, 3, 4)) and QuickWatch **(right-click on variable / Debug / QuickWatch**) windows to watch variables and expressions during a debugging session. The difference is that the Watch window can display several variables, while the **QuickWatch** window displays a single variable at a time.

Source : [Watch and QuickWatch Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The regular watch window will also show a function return value (so you would have to execute whatever statement you are interested in and possibly even step out of the function). Such unnamed expressions come at the head of the watch window list. The keystroke under my key map is alt+4, you can also get there via Debug->Windows->Watch...